# connect (RS232 to USB )cable on linux

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, microcontroller, pic

I have a JDM programmer for pic microcontrollers but it came with RS232 port
I have bought a RS232 to USB cable with its driver for windows only and I use xubuntu 14.04LTS
I have tried dmesg and lsusb , it shows that the cable is connected
But when I try to burn hex file to the programmer it gives me this output

```
<p><b>PICPgm Development Programmer Version 2.8.1.0
http://picpgm.picprojects.net
Copyright 2002-2014 Christian Stadler (picpgm@gmx.at)
(built on Dec 29 2014 at 22:32:45)
==================================================================

Autodetecting Programmer ...

Warning: Unable to open parallel port I/O driver!
         Installing driver requires admin/root rights!

Error! PIC Programmer not found! Check connection!</b></p>
```

Comment: Wellcome to StackOverflow. Your question is off-topic here since it isn't about programming. In fact, even the current state of this question would be too poor for AskUbuntu. It would need a massive rewrite.

Comment: You are asking about an error with a tool. Most likely a configuration error, not a programming error. In fact, there is absolutely nothing related with code.

Comment: It is a question about a tool. There isn't much information. Just that you have a USB connector, some micro-controller, Ubuntu and that it gives a generic error when connecting.

Comment: The error message is *"Unable to open parallel port I/O driver!"* That's not a serial port.

Comment: Where could I ask this question?

Comment: After browsing some PICPgm pages, some versions seems to support parallel and others, serial interfaces. I notice your programmer is using Auto-detect mode from the cues you supplied. I see from this page http://picpgm.picprojects.net/ there is a configuration dialog: have you explored its options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. 1. JDM programmer uses the voltage from a true serial port to extract the VPP and VDD required to program any PIC controller. The USB2RS232 adapter you purchased will never work on Win or Linux no matter what you try. If you are the unlucky user of a laptop then your only option is to buy/build an USB version of a programmer that uses external power. 
2. The rrror message comes from the fact that you did not configure your programmer corectly.In the hardware section of PicPGM you have to configure your programmer and timers. Please consult the PicPGM manual and Website.